# Spark "error: type mismatch" with scala 2.11 and not with 2.12

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark

I have a strange compilation error using scala 2.11 and not with 2.12 (working with spark 2.2.1)

here my **scala** code

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.
      master("local")
      .appName("spark rmd connect import")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()


    //LOAD
    var time = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val r_log_o = spark.read.format("orc").load("log.orc")
    val r_log = r_log_o.drop(r_log_o.col("id"))
    System.currentTimeMillis() - time


    time = System.currentTimeMillis()
    r_log_o.toJavaRDD.cache().map((x:Row) => {x(4).asInstanceOf[Timestamp]}).reduce(minTs(_, _))
    System.currentTimeMillis() - time
```

**where**

```
  def minTs(x: Timestamp, y: Timestamp): Timestamp = {
    if (x.compareTo(y) < 0) return x;
    else return y;
  }
```

my **pom.xml** is configured as below

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <scalaVersion>2.11</scalaVersion>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

if i compile `<scalaVersion>2.12</scalaVersion>`

it compiles, using scala 2.11 I get the following error

> [INFO] /root/project/src/main/java:-1: info: compiling
>   [INFO] /root/project/src/main/scala:-1: info: compiling
>   [INFO] Compiling 2 source files to
>   /root/rmd-connect-spark/target/classes at 1515426201592 [ERROR]
>   /root/rmd-connect-spark/src/main/scala/SparkConnectTest.scala:40:
>   error: type mismatch; [ERROR]  found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Row =>
>   java.sql.Timestamp [ERROR]  required:
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function[org.apache.spark.sql.Row,?]
>   [ERROR]            .map((x : Row) => {x(4).asInstanceOf[Timestamp]})
>
> ### [ERROR]                           ^ [ERROR] one error found [INFO]
>
> ### [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]

NOTE: **this is not a problem of spark runtime is a problem of using scala 2.11 with spark api**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a javaRDD, so you need to use the Java api and a `org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function` instead of a Scala function.  In Scala 2.12 support was added to automatically convert Scala functions into Java SAM interfaces, which is why this code works in Scala 2.12.

Use the Scala API instead of Java if you are going to be coding in Scala.